# Install Java JRE as a startup task in service fabric

Tags: java, windows, azure-service-fabric

I added `jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe`and made a `install.cmd`

```
start /B /WAIT jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe /s SPONSORS=0
```

in my `/PackageRoot/Code`folder

added

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>install.cmd</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
    <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048"/>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

to my service manifest

added principals to application manifest

```
<Principals>
<Users>
  <User Name="Admin">
    <MemberOf>
      <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
    </MemberOf>
  </User>
</Users>
```

and run policies

```
<Policies>
  <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="Admin" EntryPointType="All" />
</Policies>
```

but for some reason JRE is not installed.

When using the CMD version above, it dont fail and i dont have any log files with information why.

I tried `jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe /s` directly in the Program and Arguments elements of service manifest also, which gave a problem has terminated with exit code 1 in the event logs - but also no real information on why it fails.

```
SetupEntryPoint:ExeEntryPointDescription { Program = jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe, Arguments = /s /L d:/javainstall.log, WorkingFolder = Work, PeriodicIntervalInSeconds = 0 ConsoleRedirectionEnabled = true ConsoleRedirectionFileRetentionCount = 5 ConsoleRedirectionFileMaxSizeInKb = 2048 } terminated with exitcode 1. CodePackageIdentifier { ServicePackageId = S-Innovations.Elastic.ElasticApplicationType_App31:S-Innovations.Elastic.ElasticServicePkg, CodePackageName = Code }:131369814689037041
```

Comment: Have you tried not using start in install.cmd and just calling the exe file directly? It creates a new context for the installation, which might be part of the problem?

Comment: yes, provided same result as if it was run directly in the service manifest.

Comment: I have found an alternative path for now, by including JRE in my package also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a setup.cmd file in a similar manner in my application, and it's working fine using **CodeBase** instead of CodePackage. Might be worth trying out. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app

Hans